# Is there a way to see what happens during program execution in detail on Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, memory-profiling

I am trying to debug a performance of my program. What would be ideal is to have a way to see in detail when was the thread doing useful work, when was it blocked by page faults, when was it executing some memory writes and reads, etc...

I would simply like to have a detailed understanding of whats going on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux kernel sources come with the [`perf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) tool that can measure a large number of performance counter, all of those you listed included, and can print statistics about it, annotate symbols, instructions and source lines with them (if debug symbols are available), and can track any process or also logical cpu cores.

Your Linux distribution will have the tool probably in a standalone package. Some hardening options of the kernel may limit what information root or non-root users can collect with it.

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting? So, how can I use perf e.g. to get a stack trace of places causing most of the page faults for example? Is there some comprehensive perf tutorial out there?

Comment: I mean, I encountered perf before, but it was mostly for getting overall statistics on the above metrics.

Comment: @SamuelHapak Well, I linked you the `man` pages. They describe all the functionality and also usually have some examples. You'll want to use `perf record` to record the performance counters, then `perf report` to report on individual symbols or maybe `perf annotate` to report on individual source code lines or assembly. There are links to the individual functions at the bottom of the `perf` man page. But I think I remember there was a good tutorial, I'll try to find it again...

Comment: @SamuelHapak Maybe the one on the linux kernel's wiki: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial. (I haven't checked the content. It might be more focused on profiling in kernel space, not user space.)

Comment: @SamuelHapak But I think I was remembering https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perf and visualizing a perf output file graphically with [hotspot](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot)